# Conditional formatting for restricted part in each cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel

Suppose we have 3 cells, with content respectively "123 (45)", "456 (67)" and "789 (89)". Is it possible to formatting the three cells based on only their first values, i.e., "123", "456", "789" ?

To make it clear:

[image]

How to still format as shown in the picture suppose I have "(XX)" following each number in each cell,

i.e., 480 (XX), 7 (XX), 112 (XX)''''''''

Comment: Yes. (How? Conditional Formatting has a formula-based option. Determine the Formula required to extract the section of the values you're interested in, convert to numbers if required, set formatting. Repeat for each specific format desired.) Depending on how specific an answer you're looking for, you may need to add more information about what type of conditional formatting you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to format the cells based on the values of the restricted parts.

Comment: it can be done with vba if you need an example i will update my answer for you

Comment: the problem is that you have to put =NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,3)) into an array, and i don't think data bar is able to recognize arrays

Comment: or how about to extract in a hidden column only the values and then apply databars

Comment: Surely i am eager to learn your example. To achieve this in a slide or somewhere else what I have done was I created two arrays in excel, respectively in 'XX(XX)' and 'XX' form. To the 'XX' array I did desired conditional formatting and hide the original number by customing cell number format. Then I overlapped the two tables by pasting  in slides, which sounds like a stupid way, IMAO.

Comment: I edited my answer, with all the possibilites, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the cell contain the same pattern for example: 123 (45)

then you can use Conditional Formatting the formula-based option and put this formula:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,3)) = 123
```

or

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,3))=B1
```

B1 if you want to reference to the value of some cell

and do the desired formatting

if the pattern is not the same but for example some are like: 123 (45), 1234 (46) then:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)) = 123
```

or

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)) =B1
```

**EDIT**

The easy way of doing that is:

In another column next to the column  which has tha data put this formula:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

then you can apply data bars conditional formatting, inside the conditional formatting options for data bar there is a check box "show bar only" and the result is going to be something like this:

[image]

Another way is in another column put the formula:

```
=A1&"     "&REPT("|",NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))/5)
```

[image]

or this

```
=A8&"     "&REPT("∙",NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A8,FIND(" ",A8)-1))/5)
```

[image]

there is no other easy way of doing that cause data bar conditional formatting does not accept array formula.

You can do it anyway with a macro in the sheet which has the data copy and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lRow As Long

Dim data As Range

Set data = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

If Not Intersect(Target, data) Is Nothing Then

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr() As Double

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lRow

Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

ReDim Preserve arr(i)
arr(i) = Left(myrange, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", myrange) - 1)


Next i

Dim MaxValue As Long

MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(arr)

For i = 1 To lRow
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

With myrange.Interior
  .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
  .Gradient.Degree = 180
  .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
  .Color = RGB(13, 71, 161)
  .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1 - (arr(i) / MaxValue))
  .Color = RGB(13, 71, 161)
  .TintAndShade = 1
End With

With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
  .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  .TintAndShade = 1
End With

Next i
End If
End Sub
```

So with this code every time you put a new data in the column it will automatically format it like the image below. I have tested and it works just paste it in your sheet, not in a module and change the ranges as fits to you.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: in what sense stripes, can you provide a photo of what you want to do?

Comment: Well, appreciate it. My goal is to format the cells based on the values of my interested part.  In this case, 456 (XX) should have a longer strip displayed than 123(XX)

Comment: @FuminWang did you checked my last answer, the vba code will do the requested task for you, check it and tell me if it helped.

Comment: That's helpful, let me take time to digest all of them, thank you !

Comment: Just change the range, I have set it to range A. You can replace A with your range